# onkeyup key-value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a standard textbox and I've got jQuery on the page. I want to act when the user types a space into the textbox. I am, however, unsure of how to do this.

Can anybody give me a hand with this please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var KEYS = {
    SPACE: 32
};

$("#textbox").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === KEYS.SPACE) {
        console.log("Space key pressed");
    }
});
```

References:

- http://docs.jquery.com/Events/keyup
- http://www.asciitable.com